# How to update Azure DeviceTwin NESTED desired properties? (Java)

Tags: azure, nested, hashset, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I am using the `com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot:iot-service-client:1.16.0` library (Java) for working with Azure IoT Devices. I am trying to "update" some properties, however they nested and I am having trouble updating them.

My DeviceTwin Json looks like this:

[image]

The azure library comes with a `setDesiredProperties` function that takes a `HashSet<Pair>` as its argument. So I can easily update `firmwareVersionToDownload" , "serverConfigurationVersion", or "webContentDataType" keys because they are **Top-Level** entities, like this (as seen in the image above):

```
myIotDeviceObjectInJava.setDesiredProperties(new HashSet<Pair>() {{
            add(new Pair("myKey", "myNewValueForKey"));
        }});
```

I need to set the value for the keys "object1" & "object2" to the value of "null", but they are 2/3 levels deep. Can anyone help me to do this?

I've tried creating a new HashSet with other nested HashSet's until I reached the level (third) where I then passed in a new Pair("object1","null") object to set to null, but it ended up just deleting my entire `"serverConfiguration"` block of code (example below):

```
updateProperties(new HashSet<Pair>() {{
            add(new Pair("serverConfiguration", new HashSet<Pair>() {{
                add(new Pair("nestedIpData1",new HashSet<Pair>() {{
                    add(new Pair("object1","null"));
                }}));
            }}));
        }}
        );
```

Do I need to iterate over the top level objects and get the value object of `serverConfiguration` and then set it somehow that way?

Answer (score 1):

I went ahead and tried do it myself using the sample [Get started with device twins (Java)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-java-java-twin-getstarted) with some tweaks in the Service App.

**Note: I used `com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot:iot-service-client:1.25.0`**

In order to understand the type of object returned when reading a desired property with a nested Json Object I first edited the Twin directly in the Azure Portal and then debuged the code to check the type of ojbect:

```
DeviceTwin twinClient = DeviceTwin.createFromConnectionString(iotHubConnectionString);
DeviceTwinDevice device = new DeviceTwinDevice(deviceId);
Set<Pair> currentDesired = device.getDesiredProperties();
```

[image]

You can notice that "ServerConfiguration" and "Object3" values are of type TwinCollection (check [TwinCollection.java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-java/blob/master/deps/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/sdk/iot/deps/twin/TwinCollection.java) code comments to understand it better)

Therefore, in order to set object1 and object 2 to null :

```
        TwinCollection nestedIpData1 = new TwinCollection();
        TwinCollection object1 = new TwinCollection();
        TwinCollection object2 = new TwinCollection();
        TwinCollection object3 = new TwinCollection();

        object1.putFinal("hostname", "my.host.name1");
        object1.putFinal("netmask", "1.1.1.1");
        object1.putFinal("ip", "1.1.1.1");
        object1.putFinal("cloudIp", "1.1.1.1");
        object1.putFinal("gateway", "1.1.1.1");

        object2.putFinal("hostname", "my.host.name2");
        object2.putFinal("netmask", "2.2.2.2");
        object2.putFinal("ip", "2.2.2.2");
        object2.putFinal("cloudIp", "2.2.2.2");
        object2.putFinal("gateway", "2.2.2.2");

        object3.putFinal("hostname", "my.host.name3");
        object3.putFinal("netmask", "3.3.3.3");
        object3.putFinal("ip", "3.3.3.3");
        object3.putFinal("cloudIp", "3.3.3.3");
        object3.putFinal("gateway", "3.3.3.3");

        nestedIpData1.putFinal("object1", null);
        nestedIpData1.putFinal("object2", null);
        nestedIpData1.putFinal("object3", object3);

        Set<Pair> desiredProperties = new HashSet<Pair>();
        desiredProperties.add(new Pair("serverConfiguration", nestedIpData1));

        device.setDesiredProperties(desiredProperties);

        // Update the device twin in IoT Hub
        System.out.println("Updating device twin with  nestedobject");
        twinClient.updateTwin(device);
```